# CircleCI: Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, circleci

I cannot solve error while updating circleCI 1.0 to 2.0.
What I want to do using circleCI is very simple, just running rspec test.

The error is

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

My .circleci/config.yml file is

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.1-node-browsers
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: test
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7
        environment:
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=''
    steps:
      - checkout

      # Restore bundle cache
      - restore_cache:
          key: rails-demo-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

      # Bundle install dependencies
      - run: bundle install --path vendor/bundle

      # Store bundle cache
      - save_cache:
          key: rails-demo-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle

      # Database setup
      - run: mv config/database.yml.sample config/database.yml
      - run: RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
      - run: RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:schema:load

      # Run rspec in parallel
      - type: shell
        command: |
          bundle exec rspec --profile 10 \
                            --format RspecJunitFormatter \
                            --out test_results/rspec.xml \
                            --format progress \
                            $(circleci tests glob "spec/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)

      # Save test results for timing analysis
      - store_test_results:
          path: test_results
```

My config/database.yml file is

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
```

ruby version is 2.1.4, and mysql version is 5.7.10

Comment: Can you share your git repo or circleci job URLs?